# How to Refund Stripe Subscription charged amount?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I am Implementing a case in which i need to cancel customer subscription and refund amount for the same.
I am able to cancel Subscription using

```
$sub = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve({SUBSCRIPTION_ID});
$sub->cancel();
```

now i have to refund charged amount

```
 $refund = \Stripe\Refund::create(array(
  "charge" => "{CHARGE_ID}"
));
```

here `CHARGE_ID` is compulsory. no option like `SUBSCRIPTION_ID`.

As it charged customer automatically i am not able to store `CHARGE_ID`. so how can i refund that subscription amount??

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: yes i have checked that but CHARGE_ID is required and i am not having CHARGE_ID.

Comment: did you check the Stripe documents [here](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/canceling-pausing)?

Comment: yes i had checked. it's not refunding subscription.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave that will only cancel further charging through subscription , will not refund charged amount

Comment: not it's not case like extra charged amount

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152764/discussion-between-meera-tank-and-mittul-at-technobrave).

Comment: Subscription retrieve returns an object that contains a customer_id. You can then use that customer_id to get the charge_id from the customer lookup.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave yes i have solved it , i'll put it as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Meera, I see you solved your problem, my solution was:
 1. once you've cancelled your Subscription
 2. get all Invoice Collection using the subscriptionId from the Subscription
 3. pull the first Invoice from the Invoice Collection
 4. create a Refund using the chargeId from the Invoice

```
$subscriptionId = $objSubscription->id;
$objInvoiceCollection = \Stripe\Invoice::all([
    'subscription' => $subscriptionId
]);

if ($objInvoiceCollection->total_count === 0) {
    throw new \Exception("warning: \$subscriptionId={$subscriptionId} - no invoices found!");
} else {
    $objInvoice = current($objInvoiceCollection);
}

$chargeId = $objInvoice->charge;
$objRefund = \Stripe\Refund::create(['charge' => $chargeId]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i had implemented same way, but i used foreach for all $chargeId.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to refund only the unused credit from the subscription then try this

```golang
    subscription, err := c.subscription(id)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    cancelTime := time.Now().Unix()
    _, err = sub.Cancel(subscription.ID, &stripe.SubscriptionCancelParams{
        Prorate:    stripe.Bool(true),
        InvoiceNow: stripe.Bool(true),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    invItr := invoice.List(&stripe.InvoiceListParams{
        Customer:     stripe.String(subscription.Customer.ID),
        Subscription: stripe.String(subscription.ID),
    })
    var (
        refundAmount int64
    )
    for _, i := range invItr.InvoiceList().Data {
        if i.Created >= cancelTime {
            refundAmount = i.Total * -1
            break
        }
    }
    if refundAmount > 0 {
        latestInvoice, err := invoice.Get(subscription.LatestInvoice.ID, nil)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        _, err = refund.New(&stripe.RefundParams{
            Charge: stripe.String(latestInvoice.Charge.ID),
            Amount: stripe.Int64(refundAmount),
        })
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }
```